# Connector/C++ 8.0.28 Failed in MySQL

Tags: mysql, failed-installation

[When I install MySQL, Connector/C++ 8.0.28 Failed. What should I do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYJ9R.jpg)

Comment: Software installation is off-topic. [ask] [Help] PS Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too, i installed it manually.

You can download here:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/8.0.html

Comment: So, the first step is install the connector. After that, install MySQL?

Comment: I installed MySQL first